# Rails 4 scope adding a null `id` column to result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class like this:

```
class FileDownload < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :status, -> { select('user_id') }
end
```

I'm using this scope in a controller to return a json response. This worked just fine in Rails 3.2.14. The response looked like this:

```
[{ "user_id": 1234 }]
```

After upgrading to Rails 4, suddenly the response looks like this:

```
[{ "user_id": 1234, "id": null }]
```

Can anyone explain why the null id field is being added?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `pluck`:

```
scope :status, -> { pluck(:guid, :status) }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, as it changes the response. I'm returning a json response, and using pluck changes it to this:

    `[["vzc829400fdcc44927a2f4f1e1dfd6379f", "finished"]]`